# MongoDB returning null value for keys in uppercase

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch response from MongoDB collection in java spring boot.

Below is the sample record:-

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c86193efa093d1b8d9ca3fe"),
        "name" : "name",
        "UPPERCASENAME" : "NAMEINUPPERCASE"
}
```

Below is the model class:-

```
public class modelClass {
    private String name;
    private String UPPERCASENAME;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUPPERCASENAME() {
        return UPPERCASENAME;
    }

    public void setUPPERCASENAME(String UPPERCASENAME) {
        this.UPPERCASENAME = UPPERCASENAME;
    }
}
```

And below is the query:-

```
public List<modelClass> getResponse(){
  return collection.find().into(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Below is the response on making an api call to the database:-

```
[
    {
        "name": "name",
        "uppercasename": null
    }
]
```

When I logged the document response I was able to fetch all the records correctly from DB

```
{"timestamp":"2021-03-10T21:03:29,483Z","level":"INFO","thread":"boundedElastic-1","message":":::Document Document{{_id=5c87868efa093d1b8d9ca415, UPPERCASENAME= NAMEINUPPERCASE, name=name}}"}
```

It seems that query is returning correct values, and somehow the data is not getting mapped correctly with the model object because of case sensitive issue.

So as you can see from the api response I was able to fetch the value for key 'name' since it was in lowercase, but was not able to fetch value for key 'UPPERCASENAME' which is in uppercase. Also in the response magically 'UPPERCASENAME' has changed to 'uppercasename'.

Can someone please help me to understand the root cause of the issue, and also a possible solution for the same?

Any help will be appreciated.

PS:- I am new to mongoDB, so please understand my situation if I am missing something basic.

Comment: Spring and Spring Data uses as lot "convention of over configuration" and the convention is: camelCase. If you want to use something else, you can use the `@Field` annotation and provide your own name.

Comment: It is baffling (and sad) that the documentation is silent on whether or not field names are case sensitive.  That said, if the documentation is silent, the behavior can change without notice.

Comment: @BenjaminM I think the issue is with Mongo, or possibly in the Mongo driver.

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name to camel case.

so change:

```
private String UPPERCASENAME;
```

to:

```
private String uppercaseName;
```

Then it should get parsed correctly